# GIT - make clone shallower

Tags: git

I have a lot of branches off of my main development.

I use GIT clones on my production server. I recently found out about --single-branch which uses dramatically less space to write git files. Is there any way I can convert existing git installations to a more shallow version (as if I did --single-branch) without re-initializing the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll work from the assumption that a single-branch repo would be smaller.  This matches my experience, but considering the handling of pack files I can't say with 100% certainty that this will always work.  In the worst case I guess you could periodically run the "cleanup procedure" toward the end of option 2, to make sure the local is minimal.

That said...

If you have direct access to a repo (i.e. can interact with it as a local repository) then you can do what you've asked.  But in my opinion it's easier to re-clone.  I assume you don't want to re-clone because you don't want to remove the working copy - even momentarily - from production.  If that's the case, there's a way to work around it.  But just in case there's some other reason not to re-clone, I'll spell out another approach as well.

**Option 1 - re-clone while preserving the working tree**

Basically what to do here is just create a new, separate clone, and then swap the `.git/` folder over to the old repo.  I generally don't advise messing with the `.git/` folder manually; so that's the down side to this approach, and we need to be careful.

```
cd /path/to/old/repo
mv .git ../backup.of.old.repo.git
cd ..
git clone --single-branch --branch master url/of/origin new.repo
mv new.repo/.git repo
```

Then check `git status`, do whatever other validations make sense, make sure everything is working as expected before discarding `backup.of.old.repo.git`.

**Option 2 - modify existing repo configuration**

The main thing that `--single-branch` does is to modify the fetch rules for the remote.  You can do that easily enough

```
git config remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

But your repo still *has* all the other branches (because of how it was created); it just won't go looking for them in the future.  Clearing out the existing objects is the harder part.

*Clean-up procedure:*

So first you need to get rid of all the unwanted refs.  You could do this by brute force (remove entries from `.git/packed-refs`, delete files from `.git/refs/`), but be careful if you do.  Or you can use `git branch --delete`, `git tag --delete`, etc. verifying that all are gone with something like `git for-each-ref`.

But just because all the refs are gone doesn't mean nothing can reach the unwanted commits.  You also have to nuke the reflog.  There are git commands for this, but I've never had much luck getting them to do what I want.  If you know the local reflogs aren't needed for anything else, you can `rm -r .git/logs`.

But just because nothing can reach the unwanted commits doesn't mean they're gone.  Now you need to `git gc --aggressive --prune=now`

And this should finally reduce the size of the repo, assuming those other branches were accounting for much of the space...

Answer (score -1):

Sure, just do:

```
# configure to only fetch master branch
git config --replace-all remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
# delete all remote tracking branches
git for-each-ref refs/remotes/origin --format='%(refname)' | xargs -l git update-ref -d
# reinstante the still fetched branch ref
git fetch origin
# repack the repository to throw out the dangling commits from the deleted branches
git repack -adl --depth=250 --window=250
```

This only cleans up the remote branches though.
The tags that were fetched are not identifiable, they are identical to locally created tags.
If you don't have local tags or don't mind losing or retagging them, you can replace

```
git for-each-ref refs/remotes/origin --format='%(refname)' | xargs -l git update-ref -d
```

by

```
git for-each-ref refs/remotes/origin refs/tags --format='%(refname)' | xargs -l git update-ref -d
```

to also get the tags deleted that do not point into the history of the still fetched branch.